# C++ DLL char* return issue

Tags: c++, string, pointers, dll

I have a C++ DLL function that receives a char * and also returns a char*.

The definition of the DLL function is:

```
char * scanImage( char * fileDir){
    string dir(fileDir);
    string cvStr = cvScan(dir);
    char * scanReturn = &cvStr[0];
    cout << scanReturn << endl;
    return (scanReturn);
}
```

Client function is:

```
 int main()
{
    char * ret; 
    ret = scanImage("files/stu2/1.bmp");
    cout << ret << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now the *cout* of **DLL function** prints correct output which implies the argument is being passed without any problem. But the cout of **client function** prints something like this-

[image: Outputs]

I printed **ret[i]** for testing purpose. And that always returns **-35** in range. And strlen(ret) > strlen(scanReturn).

I used **std::string** instead of char* for both argument and return. That worked perfectly. But I cannot use string *(I want to use this DLL with a VB.NET application later, string will not be good for that, **or will be?**)*.

Now how to solve this problem? I am using **Visual C++** to compile both the DLL and Client program in Visual Studio 2017 IDE.

**Update:**

```
char * scanImage( char * fileDir)
{
    string dir(fileDir);
    string cvStr = cvScan(dir);
    char * scanReturn;
    scanReturn = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* cvStr.size());
    scanReturn = &cvStr[0];
    cout << "DLL Output: " << endl << scanReturn << endl;
    return (scanReturn);
}
```

Dynamically allocated memory for scanReturn. But still I am getting the same issue.

Comment: This is the usual issue about returning pointers to local variables. The variable `cvStr` will go out of scope once the function returns, and as such will be destructed and freeing the memory it handles (the string you point to with `scanReturn`). That means `scanReturn` will point to something that doesn't exist anymore, and dereferencing that pointer will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: There are two possible solutions: Either pass a pointer to a buffer (and its length) as arguments to the function, and copy the string to that. Or allocate memory dynamically, and have the caller free it.

Comment: It works with `std::string` because the return value of `scanValue` will be moved into your string `ret`.

Comment: I have updated the question according to one of your advice. No luck @Some programmer dude

Comment: Can you please check the update? @Loris156

Comment: What you do is somewhat equivalent to e.g. `int a = 5; a = 6;` and then wonder why `a` is not equal to `5`. You also forget that C-style string are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. All strings must be terminated, and you do not allocate space for the terminator.

Comment: Can you please give me a code sample? @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Is `cvStr` an `std::string` or some other type of string?

Comment: `std::string` @VisualVincent

Comment: Your updated code does the following:
Allocate new memory (for the string you want to return)
(Note: malloc gives you a pointer to allocated memory, nothing else - this is the reason you have to cast it to your type (char))
then you overwrite the pointer you've received by mallow with the address of the std::string that goes out of scope.
You return a dangling pointer.

Comment: You have to malloc the memory (as you already do), COPY the content of the string into it (dont forget the null terminate it) and than return the pointer you've got from malloc (DONT assign it to another address, your function will leak!).

Comment: Just a quick tip - Don't add tags that aren't directly linked to your question - for example the VB.Net tag. You might think that showing your question to a wider audience is good, but tbh the vast majority of VB people don't know anything useful about c++. Cheers

Comment: @Wolfgang Thanks a lot! This is solved

Comment: Just one question: Why don't you define the function in your DLL as `std::string scanImage(const std::string & dir)`? It would avoid you all the needed memory management stuff. I mean why revert to plain C `char *` types when you can use `std::string`?

Comment: @DidierTrosset : Because he's planning on P/Invoking this in VB.NET later, in which case he needs a return type that can be marshalled to a .NET type (`char*` -> `System.StringBuilder`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
char* scanImage(char* fileDir)
{
   std::string dir(fileDir); // dir is in the scope of scanImage
   std::string cvStr = cvScan(dir); // cvStr is in the scope of scanImage
   auto scanReturn = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (cvStr.length() + 1)); // scanReturn will stay after you returned from scanImage, ensure it's big enough

   strcpy(scanReturn, cvStr); // copy content of the (local) string cvStr to scanReturn
   cout << "DLL Output: " << endl << scanReturn << endl;
   return scanReturn; // return the POINTER to the memory, malloc gave us
}
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/

Comment: Yeah! this is the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not an optimal solution, but you can use the built-in [**`std::copy()` method**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/) to make a copy of the string into a `char*`.

```
char* scanReturn = new char[cvStr.size() + 1];
std::copy(cvStr.begin(), cvStr.end(), scanReturn);
scanReturn[str.size()] = '\0'; //Null-terminate the string.

return scanReturn;
```

This gives you (more) control over the newly allocated memory, BUT this also means that you must free the memory on your own via `delete[]` when you're done with the string (which could become a little difficult when using it in VB.NET).

```
int main()
{
    char * ret; 
    ret = scanImage("files/stu2/1.bmp");
    cout << ret << endl;

    delete[] ret; //Free the string's memory when you're no longer using it.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @nsssayom : Oh well, worth a shot! What if you don't create a variable and instead call `return cvStr.c_str();` directly? (Note: you mat change the return type to `const char*`)

Comment: Vincent, please dont provide a wrong solution - this still returns a dangling pointer.

Comment: @Wolfgang : Could you please explain in what way? Which pointer is "dangling"? I'm not very familiar with C++'s memory management... (FWIW I'm also working on an update for the answer, as it didn't work for the OP anyway) -- **EDIT:** Oh wait, I think I see... The `const char*` still points to the original string, right?

Comment: @VisualVincent - yes of course, see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/ :: c_str() returns a pointer to an array that contains the null terminated sequence of the characters of the string. This pointer points to the "inner data structure" of the std::string (which guarantees sequential storage) - this means if the string goes out of scope the pointer is invalidated. This way its a dangling pointer.

Answer (score -1):

This problem is solved. And posting the solution if it helps anyone in future-

DLL Function-

```
     char * scanImage(char * fileDir)
{
    string dir(fileDir);
    string cvStr = cvScan(dir);
    char * scanReturn;
    scanReturn = (char*) CoTaskMemAlloc((cvStr.size() + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(scanReturn, cvStr.c_str());
    cout << "DLL Output: " << endl << scanReturn <<endl;
    return scanReturn;
}
```

Client Function-

```
int dll_client()
{
    char * ret = scanImage("files/stu2/1.bmp");
    cout << endl << ret << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will leak, dll_client have to free the memory scanImage allocated.
strcopy with cvStr.c_str() doesn't need a extra line adding the null terminator, c_str() guarantees the null terminator.

Comment: How can I free the memory allocated to scanImage using dll_client? just `free(scanImage);`? @Wolfgang

Comment: free corresponds to malloc, delete corresponds to new... just take a look at the cplusplus.com references. It's all there!